# Hosting multiple domains in exchange server 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, domain

My company recently acquired another firm. I am thinking of bringing their mailboxes onto our email server (Exchange Server 2003).

1. Can I host multiple domains on my exchange server? Where can I find information on this?
2. Can I do this without creating another Active Directory domain?

I would prefer to make them a regular user in my current domain (mycompany.com) but have email addresses as theircompany.com

Edit ~ Also, how do I handle reverse lookup? Since I'll be pointing their MX to my current server email.mycompany.com, when they send emails as user@theircompany.com, would't it reverse to email.mycompany.com? Would this cause a problem for reverse lookup?

Answer (score 3):

You can host email for multiple domains in Exchange Server 2003. You need to add the new domain to your Recipient Policy in Exchange System Manager (you probably only have the Default Recipient Policy so it should be easy to find). You then need to create users (with mailboxes) for these new users. After the users\mailboxes are created they'll get all of the email addresses from your Recipient Policy and you can then set which email address you want to be their primary email address in the properties of their user accounts.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319201

Comment: I would also have to point their MX to my email server, but how do I handle Reverse Lookup? Currently I had my ISP created a PTR for email.mycompany.com.